# changing "application files" folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, publish

i understand that some files get published to this folder in my application. i want all the files to be in the same folder. how do i do this?

meaning that i want the setup.exe and everything to be in one folder after i have published the application. i dont want to have an application files folder at all

Comment: Added the `visual-studio` and `publish` tags because this question is more about how the compiler and IDE work than the vb.net language itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting hung up on what the IDE looks like when you create a Setup project.  There is no "application files" folder, the Setup project creates a setup.exe file when it is built.  That's the only file that you need to distribute to your client.

The "application files" node on the screen is simply a container in which you can put files while you create your Setup project.  Those files will be available in the application's install directory *after* your client runs the setup.exe installer on her machine.

Actually run the setup.exe on your machine to see what it will look like on your client's machine.

Comment: it says cannot download application because missing required files when i delete application files folder and just leave setup.exe

Comment: "download application", I don't know what you are doing.  Update your question with the steps you took to put your setup project together.

Comment: i just went to build->publish and clicked finish

Comment: Okay, that's ClickOnce deployment, not a Setup project.  Yes, you need to copy the publish directory, including "Application Files" to, say, a web server.  Is this really what you want to do?  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: I'm guessing you have an Express edition.  Setup projects are only supported in the retail edition.  You could try Wix, not sure if the learning curve is worth the VS license fee.