# publishing app in vb.net and creating setup.exe

Tags: vb.net

i am publishing an app in vb.net. it's creating setup.exe and a folder called application files. i am told that setup.exe is stand alone and does not need any other files. is this right? because when i put setup.exe in a different directory it says that some files are missing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616058/changing-application-files-folder-in-vb-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the "Setup and Installation Package" project from within visual studio, then that's not the case. The actual setup files are the .MSI file and setup.exe is just a placeholder for the Windows Installer application.

If you're using ClickOnce, then you need the entire published directory (especially the manifest, as that tells the ClickOnce protocol where everything is at.

That said, other installer creation systems work differently.

Comment: how do i use setup and installation package?

Comment: "setup.exe is just a placeholder": Setup.exe is a so-called bootstrapper, it makes sure that all pre-requisites get installed (e.g. the .NET Framework) and then launches the MSI.

Comment: @every_answer - the express systems don't support the "setup and installation package" project.
@0xA3 - For the life of me, I could not remember the word "bootstrapper" this morning.